# Programming skills are an important criteria for "whom/who" we choose to hire. Which is correct?

Tags: grammar, whom

1. Programming skills are an important criteria for whom we choose to hire.
2. Programming skills are an important criteria for who we choose to hire.

Which one is grammatically correct?

I'm guessing it's the second, but I have no idea. But there is also  *for whom the bell tolls.*

Comment: *Programming skills are an important **criterion** for **which** we choose to hire.*

Comment: On second thought, both sentences are correct if you mean to say that programming skills highly influence your decision on whom you hire; the former is more formal, the latter less so, and that is all. *Criteria*, however, is the plural form of singular *criterion*.

Comment: Programming skills are an important criterion **by** which we choose who(m) to hire. (whom and who both work - whom sounds a bit pompous)

Comment: This question has been asked ALREADY.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. To **whom** is programming skills important? The employer or the programmer being hired? If you're not sure about which one to choose, always use "who" it's never wrong.

Comment: Avoid ambiguity and doubt: "Programming skills are an important criteria *in those* we choose to hire"

Comment: The sentence expresses the idea poorly and in a verbose manner. Let's hope the code is more concise than the prose.  *The person we hire must have good programming skills.*

Comment: @medica: The criteria cannot be "in *those*". They can be "in our *choice* of whom to hire."

Answer (score 0):

A good rule for contemporary English is never use "whom".  It's dead, and it sounds stuffy and old-fashioned to use archaic forms.  In the sentences you ask about, I'd write "whoever". Also, you need to use the singular form "criterion".

Comment: I don't think this is a good rule at all. "whom" may sound stuffy to some but not to others, and it is correct to use "whom" when the syntax calls for an object.

Answer (score -1):

The word who can only be used when it is the subject of a verb. That might sound confusing, but it just means it is like the words I, he, she, we, and they. Just like who, each of these words can only be the subject of a verb. The difference with who is that some people are unsure when to use who and whom. Well, confusing that pair is no different from confusing these pairs: I/me, he/him, she/her, and they/them.

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence. I'd say "whom can only be used when it is the object of a verb". Who can be used both as subject and object nowadays.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Or when it is the object of a preposition. ;)

Comment: I agree with you when spoken but I believe my theory to be correct when written.

Comment: @Anonym: Yes, when it's an object of anything.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. I assume you would recommend *"whom"*. The problem is that *"whom"* gives you a garden-path sentence, where you have to change your grammatical parsing while you're reading it. Because then it sounds like *"whom"* should be the object of the preposition *"for"*, when it's actually not.

Comment: Oh sorry, and yes I would.